# How to get result in Java from native c++ Function defined with Qt(QJniEnvironment::RegisterNatives)

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, qt6

I'm using Qt6.2.4, and trying to get answer from C++ in Java.

```
Logic:
C++ calls Java method, who calls C++ Method.
C++ Method (Hello from C++/Qt)
Java Method (Java:  + C++ Method)
and starter C++ Method set result on Button

My expectations:
"Java: Hello from C++/Qt",
But i see:
"Java: null"

My code:
https://github.com/dail45/JNItestw
(Sorry, i can't write code here. Editor raise warnings)
```

From console i know that:
cppNativeFun really running (I see Hello from Java 0)
What i did wrong? How to get result from nativeFun (Java)?
What i need do that get "Hello from C++/Qt" without "null"?

P.s.
Sorry for the design and code, the built-in editor constantly complains that I highlighted the code incorrectly.

Udp:
./JNItestw.pro
QT       += core gui

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    widget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    widget.h

FORMS += \
    widget.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
OTHER_FILES += \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/src/org/example/JNItest/MyJNI.java
```

./main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

./widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto activity = QJniObject(QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());
    QJniObject MyJni = QJniObject("org/example/JNItest/MyJNI",
                                  "(Landroid/app/Activity;)V",
                                  activity.object<jobject>());
    QJniEnvironment env;
    jclass objectClass = env->GetObjectClass(MyJni.object<jobject>());
    JNINativeMethod methods[] = {{"nativeFun", "()Ljava/lang/String;", reinterpret_cast<void*>(cppNativeFunction)}};
    env->RegisterNatives(objectClass, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
    env->DeleteLocalRef(objectClass);
    layout->addWidget(btn);
    btn->setText("click me");
    btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {padding: 25px;}");
    QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() {
        auto activity = QJniObject(QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::context());
        QJniObject MyJni = QJniObject("org/example/JNItest/MyJNI",
                                      "(Landroid/app/Activity;)V",
                                      activity.object<jobject>());
        QJniObject res = MyJni.callObjectMethod("jniFun", "()Ljava/lang/String;").object<jobject>();
        this->btn->setText(res.toString());
    });
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

int counter = 0;
jstring Widget::cppNativeFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        qDebug() << "Hello from java!" << QString::number(counter++);
        return QJniObject::fromString("Hello from C++/Qt!").object<jstring>();
    }
```

./widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QJniObject>
#include <QJniEnvironment>
#include <jni.h>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(this);
    static jstring cppNativeFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

./android/src/org/example/JNItest/MyJNI.java

```
package org.example.JNItest;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MyJNI
{
    private final Activity m_MainActivity;
    public MyJNI(final Activity MainActivity) {
        m_MainActivity = MainActivity;
    }
    public native String nativeFun();
    public String jniFun() {
        String a = nativeFun();
        System.out.println(a);
        return "Java: " + a;
    }
}
```

./android/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.example.JNItestw" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="JNItestw" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false">
        <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:label="JNItestw" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="unspecified">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="JNItestw"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value=""/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
<!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Craft a [mre] (a MRE) and you should have no trouble convincing the server accept your code. That said, making a MRE usually results in you finding the solution yourself and not needing to ask the question. Make the MRE early in the question-asking process and usually you're done.

Comment: MRE is done in my github URL (It's not my project, is my test project(for testing and asking questions))

Comment: The github link is not as useful as you expect. The goal of Stack Overflow is to create a public repository of high quality questions and answers. In order for a question to be high quality, it must be able to withstand the test of time and still be just as useful to a reader in ten years as it is to the asker today. Links make that hard because you can't count on the linked page to be accessible and unchanged in the future. To get around this problem, all information necessary to answer the question must be contained within the question.

Comment: Wow. I inserted the code. You may not believe it, but when I asked a question, the editor constantly complained about incorrectly formatted code. And I can't remove Logic of my test code inhighlightning as code, (Editor find code without inhighlightning).

Comment: Not as much code here as I expected. I figured you were tripping over the code-to descriptive-text ratio. Maybe it's less strict on edits or maybe you'd stumbled over a bug in the code that handles the initial submission. Should be enough here for someone more skilled in these technologies than I to figure out the problem now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okey... I read part of this book: https://www.informit.com/store/java-native-interface-programmers-guide-and-specification-9780201325775 and get some info.

```
jstring Widget::cppNativeFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        return (*env).NewStringUTF("Hello from C++/Qt!");
}
```

- It's true. I finally see on my button "Java: Hello from C++/Qt!"